# Correlation vs identity: a=b, b=c, but a != c?

Tags: statistics, correlation

I analyze a dataset - the result of a survey asking people several yes/no questions. I find a moderate positive correlation (~0.5), very statistically significant, between those who answer yes to question (let's call it) a and those who answer yes to b. Similar correlation between those who answer yes to b and those who answer yes to c. However, the correlation between affirmative to a and affirmative to c is very weak ( ~ 0.1) and much higher p value, barely significant.
 
That seems unexpected. With limited knowledge of statistic, I want to ask - is it also informative? Had it been an identity, then if a=b and b=c, it means that a=c. With correlation, it's obviously not the case, but my intuition argues that correlation can be seen as a weak form of identity, so if a and b are similar and b and c are similar - so should be a and c. The fact that they are not indicated that something is driving the correlation down. There must be a subpopulation that behaves very differently - possibly (likely?) population showing a negative correlation between a and c. Am I right?

Comment: So, the half of Lumberjacks also like Checkered Shirts. Independently of that, half of Checkered Shirt wearers appreciate a Soy Latte. Is it then unexpected to observe that only some of Lumberjacks would have a Soy Latte?

Comment: Some - not at all. But quantitatively. If ALL lumberjacks wore ONLY Checkered Shirts and ALL Checkered Shirts would come with Soy Latte attached to their pocket.... well, what a wonderful world it would be. But also, every Lumberjack could offer you Soy Latte. But say, only 80% of Checkered Shirt would come with Soy Latte and yet only 5% of Lumberjacks wore a Checkered Shirt with Soy Latte... the more I think of it, the more it seems you can tell something about what Lumberjacks think of Soy Latte. If they were impartial to it, 80% of them would have.